# Adobe Reader X doesn't get started with Intent

Tags: android, pdf, adobe-reader

I have a local PDF file saved to my app folder. path is the URI pointed to the PDF file.
The following code is used to view the PDF.
When I installed adobe reader 9.2 for android, PDF file opens with bullets on PDF not showing.
I removed Adobe Reader 9.2 and installed X instead, the same code will not open the PDF.
Android knows the reader installed, so I didn't get error message. I didn't get any exception either.
When I manually start up adobe reader, it happily opens my PDF.

Both emulator and Samsung phone have the same results.

Any idea what's going on here?
Thanks in advance.

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
            if (activities.size() > 0) {
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, R.string.msg_no_application_available_to_view_pdf, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Comment: Found the reason - Adobe Reader X is very slow to startup. after I added a 10 seconds counterdown timer after the call startActivity(intent); to force the following code to wait, everything is fine.